# How to programmatically add a LinkItem to a LinkItemCollection

Tags: episerver

I know the question sounds simple but it's actually tricky.

We have a page (CoursePage) that is cloned first before setting its properties at runtime.

```
PageData clone = existingCoursePage.CreateWritableClone();
coursePage = (CoursePage)clone;

// set properties....
// RelevantCourseInformationCollection is a LinkItemCollection

coursePage.RelevantCourseInformationCollection.Add(new LinkItem { Href = "google.com", Text = "Google" });
```

and I'm getting a null LinkItemCollection.

Comment: How have you tried to solve this problem before asking this question?

Comment: I did my research first

Comment: Where are you seeing that the LinkItemCollection is null? What are you doing after you add the new LinkItem? Does the page you are cloning already have LinkItems in the LinkItemCollection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems likely that your existing page does not currently have any items in the RelevantCourseInformationColletion. If this is the case, the property will be null and you will have to assign it a new LinkItemCollection instance before trying to add any LinkItems.

```
coursePage.RelevantCourseInformationCollection = new LinkItemCollection();
coursePage.RelevantCourseInformationCollection.Add(new LinkItem { Href = "google.com", Text = "Google" });
```

Or if you prefer the shorthand:

```
coursePage.RelevantCourseInformationCollection = new LinkItemColletion { { new LinkItem { Href = "google.com", Text = "Google" } } };
```